# Share HttpContext.Current.Session between .net 2.0 and mvc 3 applications

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-mvc-3

We currently have a legacy .NET 2.0 application were users can log in and do some stuff. Now we're adding a new module in MVC 3 (for logged users only) that will be running in the same IIS server under .NET 3.5 in <strike>in a different app pool</strike> different virtual directories.

The main goal would be to avoid:

1. (from 2.0 --> to MVC 3) users having to login again to the mvc app
2. (from MVC 3 --> to 2.0) we don't wan't to loose the original session information created during the login, an perhaps modified in the mvc app.

Currently all session data is stored in a `HttpContext.Current.Session` object, so what can we do to share this object between these two apps?

**EDIT**

We're currently analysing the Session State Server Mode to implement this...

Comment: Why are you using a different app pool?

Comment: @John That was a suggestion from the IIS admin, not really an obligation. Can they live inside the same app pool?

Comment: yes. They both use the same version of the CLR (2.0).

Comment: @John great, thank you! How about the session sharing issue, do you have any ideas?

Comment: my idea is that, if you use the same app pool, you may be able to share Session.